# jQuery new instance of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, object

I've got a little problem with creating new instances of object.

```
(function ($) {
$.Graph = function (config) {
    jQuery.extend(true, self.options, config || {});

    // do something

    return this;

}

$.Graph.prototype = {
    data: [],
    options: {...}
}
}(jQuery));
```

Problem is if I create two instance of this object:

```
Graph1 = new $.Graph({'container': 'graph1',...});
Graph2 = new $.Graph({'container': 'graph2',...});
```

and after

```
console.log(Graph1.options.container);
console.log(Graph2.options.container);
```

I've got for both of them result 'graph2'. I think, that first instance has been overwritten by second.
How can I do it please. May be it's possible do it by jQuery "plugin", but I don't prefer it for this case of Object/Class.

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FxnQ2/3/

Comment: What is `self.options`?

Comment: oh sorry, it shoud be this.options, I tried something

Answer (score 0):

The problem is since there is a `option` object in the prototype hierarchy your code modifies the shared object every time instead of creating a new options object for each instance of Graph.

One possible solution is to have a different default options object like

```
(function ($) {
    $.Graph = function (config) {
        this.options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $.Graph.defaultOptions, config || {});
        return this;
    }

    $.Graph.prototype = {
        data: []
    }
    $.Graph.defaultOptions = {
        container: '',
        some: 'other'
    }
}(jQuery));


Graph1 = new $.Graph({
    'container': 'graph1'
});
Graph2 = new $.Graph({
    'container': 'graph2'
});


console.log(Graph1, Graph1.options.container);
console.log(Graph2, Graph2.options.container);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FxnQ2/)